# Failure to implicitly convert class to base class when using LINQ IEnumerable.ToDictionary()

Tags: c#, linq, abstract-class, .net-4.5, implicit-conversion

I have the following situation which is confusing me.

Given:

```
public class ThermoRawFile : MsDataFile { }

public abstract class MSDataFile { }
```

I am unable to run this LINQ IEnumerable.ToDictionary() method:

```
IEnumerable<string> rawFiles;
Dictionary<string, MSDataFile> dataFiles = rawFiles.ToDictionary(
    file => file,
    file => new ThermoRawFile(file)
);
```

as the compiler gives the following error:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,CSMSL.IO.Thermo.ThermoRawFile> to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,CSMSL.IO.MSDataFile>"
```

Why cannot it implicit convert `ThermoRawFile` into `MSDataFile` when it is a simple inheritance?

This works just fine:

```
 MSDataFile dataFile = new ThermoRawFile("someFile.raw");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error does not say that it cannot convert `CSMSL.IO.Thermo.ThermoRawFile` to `CSMSL.IO.MSDataFile`, only that it cannot convert a generic dictionary type based on `CSMSL.IO.Thermo.ThermoRawFile` to a generic dictionary type based on `CSMSL.IO.MSDataFile`. This is expected, because these types are not covariant.

You can fix this by supplying a cast:

```
IEnumerable<string> rawFiles;
Dictionary<string, MSDataFile> dataFiles = rawFiles.ToDictionary(
    file => file,
    file => (MSDataFile)new ThermoRawFile(file)
);
```

Comment: Why not use an *actual* cast instead of `as`? Usually the presence of `as` implies that the conversion *may* fail, and will be handled with a nullity check.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, that was somewhat misleading. This is now fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that type inference has inferred your `ToDictionary` call to be:

```
rawFiles.ToDictionary<string, string, ThermoRawFile>(...)
```

That means the returned value will be of type `Dictionary<string, ThermoRawFile>`, and there's no conversion from that to `Dictionary<string, MSDataFile>` (partly because dictionaries are invariant in general, and partly because all classes are invariant).

Now you *can* cast the value selection part to make type inference work:

```
var dataFiles = rawFiles.ToDictionary(
    file => file,
    file => (MSDataFile) new ThermoRawFile());
```

Or you could just explicitly specify the type arguments:

```
var dataFiles = rawFiles.ToDictionary<string, string, MSDataFile>(
    file => file,
    file => new ThermoRawFile());
```

That will still be fine, as the compiler can convert the lambda expression `file => new ThermoRawFile()` into a `Func<string, MSDataFile>`.

Comment: @Moop: It would really have helped if you'd stated the error message rather than just "doesn't work". I'll look at it in a minute.

Comment: @Moop: Fixed now. Just had the wrong number of type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with covariance.  A `ThermoRawFile` is a `MSDataFile`, but a `Dictionary<string, ThermoRawFile>` is not a `Dictionary<string, MSDataFile>`.

If it were, then you could do something like this:

```
public class FooFile : MsDataFile { }

dataFiles["blah"] = new FooFile();
```

This would be putting a `FooFile` into a `Dictionary<string, ThermoRawFile>`, which would wreak all kinds of havoc.

In this case you need to construct a dictionary that is actually of type `Dictionary<string, MSDataFile>` to begin with, even if you populate it with entirely `ThermoRawFile` values.  You can do so by adding in a cast (as shown in a bunch of other answers here):

```
IEnumerable<string> rawFiles;
Dictionary<string, MSDataFile> dataFiles = rawFiles.ToDictionary(
    file => file,
    file => (MSDataFile)new ThermoRawFile(file)
);
```